# Computing 15 min Time Weighted Moving Average in Java8 Collections

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, arraylist, collections, weighted-average

How can i effectively compute a 15 mins time weighted moving average for a scientific data for the below data model and what data structure can be best utilized to perform the moving window calculations to prevent operations in multiple loops?

Below is the data model that i can query from database to get List results.

```
public class Readings{

private String sensor;
private int sequence;
private Float reading;
private int count; 

}
```

The expected result is 15 mins data (900 seconds data ) which is ∑(last 15 min reading * count in seconds)/(15*60). For first 900 seconds, it is simple straight forward calculation. But after 900th seconds, from the below sequence #23, i need to do a moving weighted average on previous records in a 15 mins /900 s period window.

> So 15 mins TWA for seq#23 will be   = (15*90
>   +14*40+13*80+12*110+11*80+10*20+11*10+10*40+11*10+10*80+9*20+10*10+9*10+10*20+9*80+8*50+7*30+6*40+5*20+4*20+3*30+2*10)/900 = 10.22

The time window moves in the next 900s window.

`Data 
 ==================================
Sensor Sequence Reading count(s)    15Min TWA = ∑ last 15 min reading * count/(15*60)
GAS     1       1.00        30      0.03
GAS     2       2.00        30      0.10
GAS     3       3.00        30      0.20
GAS     4       4.00        20      0.29
GAS     5       5.00        20      0.40
GAS     6       6.00        40      0.67
GAS     7       7.00        30      0.90
GAS     8       8.00        50      1.34
GAS     9       9.00        80      2.14
GAS     10      10.00       20      2.37
GAS     11      9.00        10      2.47
GAS     12      10.00       10      2.58
GAS     13      9.00        20      2.78
GAS     14      10.00       80      3.67
GAS     15      11.00       10      3.79
GAS     16      10.00       40      4.23
GAS     17      11.00       10      4.36
GAS     18      10.00       20      4.58
GAS     19      11.00       80      5.56
GAS     20      12.00       110     7.02
GAS     21      13.00       80      8.18
GAS     22      14.00       40      8.80
GAS     23      15.00       90      10.22
GAS     24      16.00       30      10.67
GAS     25      17.00       40      11.24
GAS     26      18.00       30      11.66
GAS     27      17.00       50      12.23
GAS     28      18.00       20      12.46
GAS     29      19.00       60      13.16
GAS     30      20.00       100     14.34`

I found the solution to complete the 15 mins moving window Time weighted average using Apache Common collections - CircularFifoQueue but wanted to know if this can be improved with a better solution as i need to run this same logic for multiple sensors and time periods every 15 mins once.

```
    List<Readings> findBySensorSn = inetService.findBySensorSn(sensorSn, session);

    Map<Short, List<Readings>> groups = findBySensorSn.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Readings::getSequence))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (Map.Entry<Short, List<Readings>> entry : groups.entrySet() ) {

        int count = 0;
        Float sum = 0f;

        for (Readings readings : entry.getValue()) {
            count = count + readings.getCount();
                    Float sum = 0f;
        Queue<Float> fifo = new CircularFifoQueue<Float>(90);
        for (Readings readings : entry.getValue()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < readings.getCount(); i++) {
            //Add readings of 10 seconds in the queue till 900 seconds
            fifo.add(readings.getReading() * 10);
            }
            System.out.println(fifo.stream().collect(Collectors.summingDouble(Float::floatValue)) / 900);

        }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on where exactly you are stuck?  Error message?  Incorrect output?  Something else?

Comment: @JoeC Updated my solution. Looking for a better code that scales for multiple sensor data efficiently.

Comment: If you have working code that you'd like to improve, you are more likely to find help on our sister site [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).